# Endless scrolling listview not working

Tags: java, android, json, listview, endlessscroll

I am developing one application. In my app I am using listview to display data from json. All the data display perfectly. But what I want is, to display first 10 objects and then loading items should show and then remaining 10 will display. My json response is as given below.

```
{
 "interestsent":
  [
   {
    "interestsent_user_id":369,
    "name":"abc",
    "profile_id":"686317",
    "image":"",
    },
    {
    "interestsent_user_id":369,
    "name":"def",
    "profile_id":"686318",
    "image":"",
    },
    {
    "interestsent_user_id":369,
    "name":"ghi",
    "profile_id":"686319",
    "image":"",
    },
     {
    "interestsent_user_id":369,
    "name":"jkl",
    "profile_id":"686320",
    "image":"",
    },
    {
    "interestsent_user_id":369,
    "name":"mno",
    "profile_id":"686321",
    "image":"",
    },
    {
    "interestsent_user_id":369,
    "name":"pqr",
    "profile_id":"686322",
    "image":"",
    },
    .................
    .................
 ]
 }
```

Interestsent.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    INTEREST_SENT_URL = "http://fshdfh.com/webservice/interestsent?version=apps&user_login_id=00";
    new GetData().execute("");
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    Log.i("DATA", "page ::onCreate onCreate onCreate  ");
    mHandler = new Handler();
    listview.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            Log.i("DATA", "page :: " + page + " totalItemsCount :: "
                    + totalItemsCount);
            mProgressbar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressbar.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressbar.show();
            count++;
            if (count < maindata.size()) {
                if (adapter != null) {

                    if (!isLoadingMore) {
                        isLoadingMore = true;
                        mHandler.postDelayed(loadMoreRunnable, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

Runnable loadMoreRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (count < maindata.size()) {
            if (adapter != null) { 
                adapter.addAll(maindata.get(count));
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(loadMoreRunnable);
                isLoadingMore = false;
                if (mProgressbar.isShowing())
                    mProgressbar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
};

static <T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> chunkList(List<T> list, final int L) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> parts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
        parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L))));
    }
    return parts;
}
private ProgressDialog mProgressbar;
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mProgressbar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressbar.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressbar.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        /*try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        /*for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            data.add(i);
        }

        return null;*/

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(INTEREST_SENT_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                interestsent = jsonObj.getJSONArray(INTEREST_SENT);
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < interestsent.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = interestsent.getJSONObject(i);
                    // creating new HashMap
                   // HashMap<ArrayList<Integer> map = new  HashMap<Integer>();
                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(INTEREST_USER_ID, c.getString(INTEREST_USER_ID));
                    map.put(INTEREST_SENT_NAME,c.getString(INTEREST_SENT_NAME));
                    map.put(INTEREST_SENT_PROFILE, c.getString(INTEREST_SENT_PROFILE));
                    map.put(INTEREST_SENT_IMAGE, c.getString(INTEREST_SENT_IMAGE));
                    map.put(INTEREST_SENT_CAST, c.getString(INTEREST_SENT_CAST));
                    map.put(INTEREST_SENT_AGE, c.getString(INTEREST_SENT_AGE)+" years");
                    map.put(INTEREST_SENT_LOCATION, c.getString(INTEREST_SENT_LOCATION));
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    data.addAll(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        maindata = chunkList(data, 50);
        Log.i("DATA", "maindata :: " + maindata.size());

        adapter = new CustomAdapterSent(maindata.get(count),
                MainActivity.this);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (mProgressbar.isShowing())
            mProgressbar.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

EndlessScroolListener.java

```
 public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;

public EndlessScrollListener() {
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
    this.currentPage = startPage;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) 
    {
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
    }
    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        currentPage++;
    }

    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // Don't take any action on changed
}
}
```

CustomAdapterSent.java

public class CustomAdapterSent extends BaseAdapter{

```
private ArrayList<Integer> mData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

 private static final String TAG_NAME="name";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE="profile_id";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
    private static final String TAG_CAST="cast";
    private static final String TAG_AGE="age";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION="location";

public CustomAdapterSent(ArrayList<Integer> mData, Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<Integer> mmData) {
    this.mData.addAll(mmData);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtView;
    TextView txtproname;
}

@Override
public View getView(int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        ///holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propicsent);
      //  holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtpronameintsent);
        //holder.txtproid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproidsent);
        //holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofilecastintsent);
        //holder.txtprofileage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileageintsent);
      //  holder.txtprofileplace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileplaceintsent);
        holder.txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no_intsent);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Log.i("DATA", "mData.get(postion) :: " + mData.get(postion));
    mData.get(postion);
    // holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
    holder.txtView.setText("Index :: " + Integer.getInteger(TAG_NAME));
    return view;
}
}
```

XML File:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/relativemainss"
android:background="@drawable/backg"
 >

 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
 </ListView>
 <TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/no_intsent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/nomessaegborder" />

<Button 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Load More"
      android:id="@+id/buttoloadmoreintsent"
     android:layout_below="@android:id/list" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to scroll down on clicking load more or replace the current 10 items with new ones? A better alternative I would suggest you to use would be "Endless scroll listview", by using it the listview will be populated when the user scrolls down, initially only the rows that fit on screen will be loaded and as the user scrolls the data will be loaded more.

Comment: you mean same like facebook scroll?how to  achive that?can you help me with that?

Comment: @AlokNair see my edited question i tried to implement as per your link..now app is running but screen display blank..no response is getting..

Comment: are you making an API call to get the response in the very beginning (in onCreate) to initialise the list?

Comment: @Swayam yes when user enters to application...one API calls and display json response..but i don't want to show all data.i want to display 10 records..and when user scrolls at bottom loading will appear and then next 10 records will appear and then so on.......

Comment: @chiragboghani: solved or still facing same issue?

Comment: @chiragboghani: coding is looking fine to me. one question how many items you are getting in first request (when user stating application)?

Comment: i am getting whole items..and when i scroll it again loads and display whole again

Comment: @chiragboghani: Good:) `Endless scroll listview` actucal meaning is your api  which is `INTEREST_SENT_URL` must support pagination. for example if you see twitter, instagram api's they also have totalcount, startcount and endcount parameter. when we want intial records then we need to send  startcount=0&endcount=10, with request and show all data in ListView, when user scroll ListView at bottom then we call api again with startcount=10&endcount=20,...and so on until endcount not equal to totalcount.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK so what is solution?..since so many days i stcuk in this..but not getting success..

Comment: @chiragboghani: not good but temporary solution is. get all data from server(as you are doing currently), partition  `aList` ArrayList in Array in equal part of size 10, show  partition[0] when user start application, on ListView scroll to bottom in `onLoadMore`  method `addaList.addAll(partition[1]);adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` until all data is not added in ListView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Show only 10 item first time in `ListView` and show more items on scroll follow following steps:

**STEP 1:** Create a `chunkList` method which divide `ArrayList` in parts of size 10:

```
static <T> List<ArrayList<T>> chunkList(List<T> list, final int L) {
        List<ArrayList<T>> parts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
        final int N = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
            parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(
                list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L)))
            );
        }
        return parts;
    }
```

**STEP 2:** Create `ArrayList` and a counter which show current part :

```
    private boolean isLoadingMore=false;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    List<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> mainArrayList;
    private int count=0;
```

**STEP 3:** In `onPostExecute` break `result` and show data in ListView:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {

              super.onPostExecute(result);
              // your code here...
               mainArrayList=chunkList(result,10);
               isLoadingMore=false;
               count=0;
               adapter = new CustomAdapterSent(Interestsent.this, 
                                            mainArrayList.get(count));
               setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

**STEP 4:** Create addAll method in Adapter to append data in current data source :

```
public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> moreData){
   this.listData.addAll(moreData);
   this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**STEP 5:** In `onLoadMore`  load more data in ListView:

```
mHandler = new Handler();
 listview.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                 if(count<mainArrayList.size()-1)
                  {
                     if(adapter !=null){
            count++;                       
            if(!isLoadingMore){
                             isLoadingMore=true;
                             mHandler.postDelayed(loadMoreRunnable,1000); 
                          } 
                      }
                  } 
        }
        });
    }

     Runnable loadMoreRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(count<mainArrayList.size())
                   {
                     if(adapter !=null){
                      count++;                       
                      adapter.addAll(mainArrayList.get(count));
                      mHandler.removeCallbacks(loadMoreRunnable);
                      isLoadingMore=false;
                      }
                  } 
        }
    };
```

Comment: @chiragboghani No i am not able to provide emai to u. if you have still any issue then please update your question with latest code

Comment: ok its ok see here one example is here..endless adapter..https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android

Comment: right now its showing 20 items at first load..and on buttons click event nothing is happen

Comment: @chiragboghani: i'm trying to make a demo for you just wait

Comment: yeah its really helpful to me..but I am getting data from json..so can tell how will i get?I am also trying...Really Thanks

Comment: My Custom adapter and Hash map etc are created with string but in your example its with integer..and also I used Aquery for image..still confuse..

Comment: any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation

Comment: can u send a demo to me pls it help me alot..thnx

Comment: @SunilChaudhary: Please ask to parajs or share specific problem which you are facing in implementing current answer.

Answer (score 1):

To have an AdapterView (such as a ListView or GridView) that automatically loads more items as the user scrolls through the items (aka infinite scroll). This is done by triggering a request for more data once the user crosses a threshold of remaining items before they've hit the end. Every AdapterView has support for binding to the OnScrollListener events which are triggered whenever a user scrolls through the collection. Using this system, we can define a basic EndlessScrollListener which supports most use cases by creating our own class that extends OnScrollListener.

You can find more about this in the below links :

[Endless Scrolling ListView in Android](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

[Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews)

[Infinite Scrolling List View](https://stevenkideckel.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/infinite-scrolling-list-view/)

A simpler approach of adding data in a listview has been show in this SO answer: [Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082523/3747037)

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Short answer: No one is going write the code for you. Long Answer: Read the suggestion given by @AlokNair and try implement it. If you face any problem in implementation feel free to post a question.

Comment: Add EndlessScrollListener to your listview in code and inside the onLoadMore event load data from webservice or some other source as you want. Refer that second link, it has good explanation and example.

Comment: Another short approach: Implement a onScroll listener on listview. You will see that listview has reached its end. There you make a json call and update your adapter.